# Recursively query column using JPA to find descendants of an object

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Let's say I have a table called Person with the columns:

```
id, name, parent_id
```

and let's say I have some data like this:

```
1, Bob, null
2, Mary, 1
3, Tim, 1
4, Sally, 3
```

So Bob has 2 kids: Mary and Tim.
And Tim has 1 kid: Sally (who grandparent is Bob)

What is the easiest way to write a JPA query such that I could find all descendants of Bob? (i.e. the result would return Mary, Tim and Sally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with plain JPA.

But if you can modify your table like this

```
id, name, parent_path(string)
```

and your data will look like this

```
1, Bob, null
2, Mary, 1
3, Tim, 1
4, Sally, 1/3
5, John, 1/3/4
6, Huge, 1/3/4/5
```

then you can query for all the descendants using like clause.
For example:

```
select p from Person p where p.parentPath like '1/%'
```

here 1 - is parentPath + entityId, so for Bob like clause looks like

```
like '1/%'
```

because Bob's parentPath is null and Bob's id is 1.

And for Sally the query will look like this

```
select p from Person p where p.parentPath like '1/3/4/%'
```

because Sally's parentPath is '1/3' and Sally's id is 4.

if you have to add a new child you just need to set its parent_path to

```
parent.parentPath + '/' + parent.id
```

Comment: The path idea is generally good but you need to be careful with "like"; "parentPath like '1/3/4%' will pick up '1/3/42' as well as '1/3/4/2'.  Usually I've worked around this by doing something like '1/3/4/%'.

Comment: Thanks for taking attention to this.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern DBMS support hierarchical queries using recursive Common Table expressions. If you can pass a plain SQL statement to the JPA layer, this can easily be done with a single statement similar to the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE people_tree (id, name, parent) as 
(
  SELECT id, name, parent_id
  FROM people
  WHERE parent name = 'Bob'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT p2.id, p2.name, p2.parent_id
  FROM people p2 
    INNER JOIN people_tree ON people_tree.id = p2.parent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM people_tree
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used nested sets for solving the same problem. Please see my question&answer : [How to show tree-view replies to message? Java & Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878687/how-to-show-tree-view-replies-to-message-java-hibernate)

I believe it's the optimal solution to query hierarhical data in the relational DBs.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 the following query works to retrieve the level each element is at, assuming you table is named Hierarchical_Test1, and contains fields "id, name, parent_id":

```
with family_tree (parent_id, id, name, level) AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
select f.parent_id, f.id, f.name, 0 as level
from dbo.Hierarchical_Test1 f
where f.parent_id=0
union all
-- Recursive member definition
select f2.parent_id, f2.id, f2.name, level + 1
from dbo.Hierarchical_Test1 as f2
inner join family_tree as f3
on f2.parent_id = f3.id
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
select parent_id, id, name, level
from family_tree
```

And this one gets you all the ancestors of an element:

```
with family_tree (parent_id, id, name, level, parent_path) AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
select f.parent_id, f.id, f.name, 0 as level, 
            CAST('/' as varchar(255)) as parent_path
from dbo.Hierarchical_Test1 f
where f.parent_id=0
union all
-- Recursive member definition
select f2.parent_id, f2.id, f2.name, level + 1, 
            CAST(
                CAST('/' as varchar(255)) 
                + CAST(f2.parent_id as varchar(255)) 
                + CAST(f3.parent_path as varchar(255))
            as varchar(255))
from dbo.Hierarchical_Test1 as f2
inner join family_tree as f3
on f2.parent_id = f3.id
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
select parent_id, id, name, level, parent_path
from family_tree
```